# How do I list unanswered messages on Mail (OS)?

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app

I am trying to do an elementary thing: I want to list my unanswered message (read or not read I don't care). 
This basic request seems to be absent from Apple Mail!!!

Comment: This "basic" request/functionality is absent from a lot of mail applications, on various platforms...

Comment: https://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html

Comment: 1. What I do is BCC myself, so all the replied threads appear with 2 blue arrows. This would not work after the sender's second reply. 2. I use "Today" mailbox. It keeps even the  older read messages that I opened even once today, as well as those received today.